# Cannot track Facebook share via like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, share, tracking

I'm currently trying to track some events on a page referring to the documentation of Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

The like button is implemented using the HTML5 version without an extra send button.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="xxx" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="auto" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div>
```

Tracking works for a usual "like/edge.create" event but is it possible to track a click to the "Post to facebook" button in the box which appears after liking a page?

I tried the "message.send" event but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you find the best way for that? I have a similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, as implemented, no there is not. The "Post to Facebook" box that pops under the Like button as a result of a like is "relatively" new (so much so that many Social Widgets accidentally hide it in their implementations).

I suspect that Facebook developers are working on updating the events to support this omission. As a work-around, I've been encourage our customers to implement sharing using `FB.ui({method:'feed',...})` which has a callback mechanism.

Hopefully I can update this answer soon with one that better allows for supporting the Like button's actions.